# Arduino, johnny-five, can it work without connected computer?

Tags: arduino-uno, azure-eventhub, johnny-five, cylon.js

I am new guy on Arduino and johnny-five. I am not clear about the way johnny-five work. JS code will run on computer or run directly on Arduino board? Besides, can we use johnny-five for IoT? because I have not found any component to support Arduino uno connect to internet(call rest api or Azure service,..)

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

johnny-five uses Firmata. The Javascript code is running on your PC, and the Arduino is basically used as a peripheral — the Firmata firmware allows software on your PC to interact with all of the Arduino's inputs and outputs, but there isn't any real "intelligence" running on the Arduino.

Yes, it's possible to use REST APIs on an Arduino without the help of an attached computer, if the Arduino has an Ethernet Shield or some other method of connecting to the internet, but do keep in mind that the Uno only has 2kB of RAM and 32kB of ROM, so there's a limit to how complex you can make things.

Comment: Thanks your feedback, so if js code runs on computer so we cannot use johnny-five for IoT project on production? Because it cannot run independently.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect arduino to a raspberry, it is not expensive.